# libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0

Tags: ubuntu, rdma

Am getting the below messages when I try to check for install devices with the command ibv_devices.

> *libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs1 libibverbs: Warning: no userspace
>   device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0*

Am running ubuntu 16.4LTS in VMWare

Output of lsmod below looks OK:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
siw                   110592  0
rdma_ucm               28672  0
ib_uverbs              65536  1 rdma_ucm
rdma_cm                57344  1 rdma_ucm
iw_cm                  49152  1 rdma_cm
ib_cm                  45056  1 rdma_cm
ib_core               212992  6 ib_cm,rdma_cm,ib_uverbs,iw_cm,rdma_ucm,siw
configfs               40960  2 rdma_cm
```

I will be grateful if I can get some help on resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ubuntu 16.04 and kernel version 4.8.7. I have mellanox connect x4 NIC for RDMA and I resolved it by installing libmlx5-1

> sudo apt-get install -y libmlx5-1

Hope it helps.